# regex to match range of numbers plus semicolon and numbers after that

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove some entries in a big xml file (8 million lines) with the following structure:

```
<sectors>
"coords": ["0" , "4"]
452;2|
460;4|
1001;6|
385;1|
463;1|
</sector>
"coords": ["0" , "8"]
629;2|
460;3|
75;3|
1010;3|
458;2|
450;1|
</sector>
```

I want to remove all entries below 1000.

Example: 452;2|

So I want a regex to capture numbers below 1000 plus the semicolon and the numbers after that in that line. It's that possible?

I am doing this in notepad ++ btw

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
^\d{1,3};.*$
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKibDY/2/)

Answer (score 2):

The regex `^\d\d?\d?;\d+\|$` will match a non-negative number below `1000`, followed by a semicolon, followed by an arbitrary non-negative number, followed by `|`.